# The words “cheap” and “inexpensive are not synonymous

Tags: grammar

My question is about correct grammar usage, and asks: 
Why do people continuously misuse the word “cheap” in the context of monetary cost when this word goes to the *quality* of a thing, instead of the word >”inexpensive” which goes to >*the cost* of something?

Comment: Your title makes a statement, you question talks about grammar but asks about semantics.  Clearly both words are grammatical. Is your question really why doesn’t everyone know what I know and why aren’t they as careful as I am in their word choice?

Comment: You might as well complain why people say "gay" for a homosexual when it used to mean happy.  Usages change.

Comment: Asking *why* here doesn't lend itself to an objective answer.

Answer (score 1):

I went to school in Chipping Barnet, England. It was called *Chipping* Barnet because it had a long-established market (or *cheap*), where one might strike bargains. Such bargains, I believe, are the origin of 'cheap', to mean 'bought at a bargain price'. It's evolved to mean inexpensive or, sometimes, inferior. It still doesn't *necessarily* mean inferior, not in the UK at least. I can say "I bought a really good pair of binoculars – and they were so cheap!", without its being a contradiction in terms. [Used next to the noun (as in "I bought a cheap pair of binoculars.") it's more likely to mean inferior – as well as inexpensive.]

So I agree that 'cheap' and 'inexpensive' are not synonyms, because 'cheap' sometimes has pejorative implications that 'inexpensive' seldom has. It is therefore safer to use 'inexpensive' in cases where 'cheap' may be ambiguous, but the *primary* meaning of 'cheap' is, I believe, inexpensive, so it's never *wrong* to use it to mean this.

Comment: Whether as you say “the primary meaning of 'cheap' is, I believe, inexpensive.”, does not

Comment: @ Rafe Montague  In response to your tantali(z)ing comment I've rewritten my last paragraph.